# Shanghai Layover

Tags: airports, shanghai

I have a 17 hour delay in Shanghai in June and am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on where i should go or where i should stay? I land at 7:10pm, and my flight is the next day at 12pm. Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Your question is unfortunately quite broad. Shanghai is one of the largest cities in the world and offers every human activity under the sun (or in your case, the stars), and we cannot possibly enumerate all of them in our format. You haven't told us anything about your interests, preferences, budget, and so on. I strongly encourage you to first take the site [tour] and review the [help], do some initial research on Google and then return here to hone your ideas, rather than try to use this site to generate them.